# CMake is unable to find MSBuild.exe

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm trying to build Assimp library using cmake (for OpenGL tutorials), but I'm unable to build the required files with CMake.

The CMakeOutput.txt ends up with: **"The system is: Windows - 10.0.18362 - AMD64"**

and the CMake GUI gives me the following:

**CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES: Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo**

```
         CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework

    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



    Build started 2/9/2020 12:30:21 PM.

    Project "E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

    PrepareForBuild:

      Creating directory "x64\Debug\".

      Creating directory "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\".

    InitializeBuildStatus:

      Creating "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

    PostBuildEvent:

      echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\

      :VCEnd

      'C:\Users\Sparkie' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

      operable program or batch file.

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\ [E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    Done Building Project "E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.



    Build FAILED.



    "E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->

    (PostBuildEvent target) -> 

      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\ [E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [E:\Softwares\assimp-4.1.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.4\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]



        0 Warning(s)

        1 Error(s)



    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.22



  Exit code: 1



Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/Softwares/assimp-4.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I've tried looking up for a solution for this issue for about weeks now, but nothing seems to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `C:\Users\Sparkie` part of a path with a space in it? Is cmake installed under that path?

Comment: yes, the path goes by: C:\Users\Sparkie ^_-  as viewed from file explorer, though CMake is not installed there

Comment: I'd change your path not to include spaces, or carats, something is getting confused

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think I realized you're right! It's because my window's username contains spaces, thus breaking the paths. Guess, i'll have to reconfigure windows now. Thanks!

Comment: Just put your folder in "" and this shall work.